# How to Make a secondary vertical axis, with labels on the left, using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to make a graph with two secondary vertical axis (y-axis), with python matplotlib.

I was using `twinx()` method, where one of the two new axis is with the default behavior (labels on the right)
and the other with **labels on the left**, like the example of tan(x) on the **figure bellow** (created in an specific software).

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm not restricted to use the `twinx()` method, if there is another way

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to add two secondary y-axis, one towards the inside:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(.5, 10, 1000)
y1 = np.cos(x)
y2 = np.sin(2 * x)
y3 = np.clip(np.tan(x * .6), -75, 75)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'dodgerblue'
ax1.set_ylabel('$cos(x)$', color=color)
ax1.plot(x, y1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'limegreen'
ax2.set_ylabel('$sin(2 x)$', color=color)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor=color)

ax3 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'crimson'
ax3.set_ylabel('$tan(.6 x)$', color=color, labelpad=-40)
ax3.plot(x, y3, color=color)
ax3.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor=color, direction="in", pad=-5)
plt.setp(ax3.get_yticklabels(), ha="right")

ax1.set_xlim(0, 12)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you JohanC. it's the second time you help me with these plots. I think the key was to use the parameters `direction="in", pad=-5`, right?

Comment: No, maybe it's the line `plt.setp(ax3.get_yticklabels(), ha="right")`. Sorry.